# Login Form safety precautions

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm using this code in my login form.Everything is working:

```
$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);
$pass=md5($password);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $pass);  
$stmt->execute();    
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id);
$stmt->fetch();

if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) { $_SESSION['name']=$id; echo'user logged in';}
else {echo'invalid username / password';}
$stmt->close();
```

But should I use something else too? Or is it enough? I'm new to prepared statements so i would like to know if syntax is well written.

Comment: For one, you should use password_hash/password_verify rather than md5. (It won't work if you've already stored the passwords as md5, though.)

Comment: What about prepared statement? Is it written well?

Comment: The prepared statement part looks fine to me, but you will need to be sure when saving your passwords to validate that they don't contain any leading/trailing spaces that would be removed by `trim`. If you do switch to using password_hash + password_verify, you'll need to change it up just a bit to select based on username only, fetch the record, and then verify the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On one hand you are using prepared statements, which are very useful to prevent SQL injection (apart from possible performance gains), the good thing about prepared statements is that making a mistake could give you incorrect results but not open the door to attackers as concatenating the query string do.

But on the other hand you are using `md5()` for hashing the password which is *not recommend for several years*. As suggested in the comments PHP now have two functions created specifically for managing passwords, [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) which are quite straightforward to use.

I strongly recommend than you dish `md5()` even if that means regeneration of password stored in the database because that function is almost useless nowdays (with md5 an attacker can easily crack all yours password in one or two days with just a computer equipped with a high-end graphics card).

*Edit:* To rehash all you existing password with `password_hash()` you could make a progressive transition, something like this:

- You add another field in the DB for the new password, by default empty.
- New users are added storing the hash obtained with `password_hash()` in the new password field, and leaving the old field empty.
- For existing users you change the login code to make it two-way:

  - If the new field is blank, you check the password against the old one, and if the password is correct you rehash the password with `password_hash()`, store it in the new field *and empty the value in the old one*. The last step is important to get rid of the insecure hash.
  - If the new field is not empty, that user has been already migrated or it's a new user, so you check against the new field with `password_verify()`.

Of course, *double-check this before putting it into production*, since you are deleting the old hash. This can take some time if there are a lot of users or they login sporadically, but if you have enough leverage you could order a mandatory login to speed up the process.

Comment: With md5, you can crack most of the passwords in one or two _minutes_ with a computer equipped with just _a web browser._ ;)

Comment: @Don'tPanic Good one, I didn't think of cloud computer.

Comment: Well, you know, crackstation, etc. I actually used it the other day to recover some passwords from a legacy system at work. easy peasy

Comment: Is it possible to change current users passwords? and how could someone crack passwords when all they know is username?

Comment: About the second question, they crack the it obtaining the original password from the hash by [brute force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack), they don't need the username (md5 is bad because is very vulnerable to brute-force attacks). Regarding the first one, I'm not sure what you mean, if you mean if an attacker could change the password, yes, it could change anything if he get write access to your server, but note that password hashing is for preventing the attacker knowing the password *even* if he get access to your server.

Comment: Currently my users have md5 generated passwords. Can I change them to password_hash + password_verify?

Comment: From the md5 hash no unless you crack it :-) (you could, but maybe your users didn't like that). Another option is making a progressive transition, I'll update the question because is too long for a comment.